# Adding text above JScrollPane which is inside a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have the below code :

```
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 120);
            textArea.setText("Error message more detail");
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ScenariosUploader.this, scrollPane, "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Which creates the below JOptionPane:

[image]

My question is how can I add text above the Pane which would say something like "Error Detail" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of giving scrollPane to `showMessageDialog` method, give it a panel (that uses [BorderLayout)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) which contains the scroll pane and an "errorDetail" label:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 120);
    textArea.setText("Error message more detail");
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel errorDetailLabel = new JLabel("Error detail:");
    panel.add(errorDetailLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

**Result:**

[image: preview]